# How to display a Layer Group in QGIS Server

Tags: gis, postgis, qgis, wms, web-feature-service

I want to display layers with QQgis server, but the group layer doesn't get displayed, instead I get a bad request response from the server :

the request : http://myserver/cgi-bin/91589/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=94043_CADASTRE&SRSNAME=EPSG:2154&OUTPUTFORMAT=GeoJSON

```
<pre>
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.2.0">
 <ServiceException code="RequestNotWellFormed">TypeName '94043_CADASTRE' unknown</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
</pre>
```

[image: Server Response]

And here is a peek at the layer section in Qgis :

[image: Layers]

Answer (score 0):

WFS services do not have any concept of layer groups which are a purely WMS feature.

You should either use a WMS request or request each layer separately with the WFS.